# jQuery sortable with conditional sublist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a little trouble with a jQuery sortable list, that has had me baffled.

The sortable list contains items and sublist items.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Mainlist items to be sortable in the normal way.
2. Sublist items to be sortable within the sublist, but also be connected to the mainlist.
3. Sublist items can only be dropped back into the original sublist.
4. No mainlist item should be droppable to a sublist.

This is what I have so far: 
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//get the index of the parent UL and add it as a data property to all child li
$('ul.sublist').each(function(i){
    var thisParentIndex = $('ul.sublist').index(this);
    $(this).data("parentIndex",thisParentIndex);
    $(this).children("li").each(function(){
        $(this).data("parentIndex",thisParentIndex);
    });
});

$('ul.mainlist').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.mainlist',
    beforeStop: function(ev, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).hasClass('hasItems') && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
});

var cancelled = false;

$('ul.sublist').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.sublist',
    out: function(ev, ui) {
        if($(this).data("parentIndex") != $(ui.item).data("parentIndex")){
            cancelled = true;
        }
        else{
            cancelled = false;
        }
    },
    stop: function(ev, ui){
        if(cancelled === true){
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
});});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="list1" class='mainlist'>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li class="hasItems">Item 3
    <ul class="sublist">
        <li>Item 1-1</li>
        <li>Item 1-2</li>
        <li>Item 1-3</li>
        <li>Item 1-4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li class="hasItems">Item 5
    <ul class="sublist">
        <li>Item 5-1</li>
        <li>Item 5-2</li>
        <li>Item 5-3</li>
        <li>Item 5-4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="hasItems">Item 6
    <ul class="sublist">
        <li>Item 6-1</li>
        <li>Item 6-2</li>
        <li>Item 6-3</li>
        <li>Item 6-4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li class="hasItems">Item 7
    <ul class="sublist">
        <li>Item 7-1</li>
        <li>Item 7-2</li>
        <li>Item 7-3</li>
        <li>Item 7-4</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4snsa6v7/6/

It's nearly there, but I can't figure out how to connect the sublist to the mainlist (and then back into the original sublist).

Any help would be appreciated with a hi-5.

Comment: Think it's sorted: http://jsfiddle.net/4snsa6v7/7/

Comment: - No, not sorted. Nearly though. When dropping a sublist item into the mainlist, it is no longer sortable within the mainlist.

Comment: Got your answer ?

Comment: @melvin I went a different route in the end; using tables and sortable tbody

Comment: Can you post your answer or your method ? I too had the issue. Somehow i solved it but still the placeholder above and below blinks such that i cannot sort

Comment: My method doesn't apply to the question; as I used individual tables (with sortable rows) instead of `ul > li > ul > li`. It was too complicated the way I initially thought.